# Cannot read property 'methods' of null

Tags: web3js, javascript, abi, openzeppelin, frontend

My teammate has deployed ERC 20 token to rinkeby test network using the truffle openzeppelin code. Now I wanted to interact with that token by using ABI and the contract address of that token using web3.eth.Contract(ABIcode, contractAddress).

I copy the ABI from the folder called C:...\build\abi\SampleToken.json because from what I understand this is where the ABI of the smart contract will be and I can just copy this line and put it in my front end code.

here is my simple JS code so far

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const App = {
    web3: null,
    account: null,
    meta: null,
    ABIcode:[
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "_name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "_symbol",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "_initialSupply",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "from",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "account",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint8",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint8"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "subtractedValue",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "decreaseAllowance",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "addedValue",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "increaseAllowance",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "recipient",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "sender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "recipient",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      }
    ],
    contractAddress: '0x48aFf6290412bD01CBf86896f32cd9de76ffDba0',

start: async function() {
    const { web3 } = this;

    try {
      // get contract instance
      //const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      /*const deployedNetwork = starNotaryArtifact.networks[networkId];
      this.meta = new web3.eth.Contract(
        starNotaryArtifact.abi,
        deployedNetwork.address,
      );  */

      this.meta = new web3.eth.Contract(ABIcode, contractAddress);
      console.log(meta);

      // get accounts
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      this.account = accounts[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Could not connect to contract or chain.");
    }
},


// put function call here

transferFrom: async function() {
  const { transferFrom } = this.meta.methods;
  const ownerWallet = document.getElementById("fromWallet").value;
  const sendToWallet = document.getElementById("toWallet").value;
  const tokenSend = document.getElementById("ammountToken").value;
  await approve(ownerWallet, tokenSend).send({from: ownerWallet})
  await transferFrom(owner.ownerWallet, sendToWallet, tokenSend).send({from: ownerWallet});
  App.setStatus("token has been send from "+ ownerWallet + " to " + sendToWallet+ " with " + tokenSend + " PHO.");
},



};

window.App = App;

window.addEventListener("load", async function() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    // use MetaMask's provider
    App.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    await window.ethereum.enable(); // get permission to access accounts
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live",);
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    App.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"),);
  }

  App.start();
});
```

the front end should only send the token to a wallet that was chosen and send to another chosen wallet and with the desired amount.

but when I ran it, I received an error of this

[image]

I believe there is something wrong with the ABI because it says that the methods in meta are 'null'. I think I can't just copy it and put it in the front end code. If so, I do not know why. I am new to this.